# Get a list without the commas

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        var slvals = [];    
        $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox-agree]:checked').each(function () {
            slvals.push($(this).val())
        })
        $( "#log" ).html('My List: ' + slvals)
    })
});;;
```

This code gives a list with commas. But I do not want the commas.

Comment: Why do you have 3 `;`s? You only need one to end the function. You do need them after each statement in your function. You need a `;` after `$("#log").html('My List: ' + slvals)`, `slvals.push($(this).val())`, and after the `.each` function

Answer (score 0):

`slvals` is a array, so use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) like an empty array or a space to join the elements in the array

```
alert('My List:  ' + slvals.join(' '))
```

Also using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create the array will be better

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        var slvals = $('input[name=checkbox-agree]:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value
        }).get()
        $("#log").html('My List: ' + slvals.join(' '))
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of putting them in an array just do the document write during the loop.

```
 $(function() {
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var slvals = []
    $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox-agree]:checked').each(function() {
        document.write($(this).val());
    })
  })
 });
```

Comment: -1. If `document.write` is called after the DOM is loaded (which is basically guaranteed given that this code happens in a click handler) it will replace the contents of the document. Generally `document.write` should only be used during the initial page load.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help. New to jquery but learning quickly.